# how to implement match query for Array in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

I have this situation

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ArrayList<String> city;
       // in city array i have    "United States-Alabama-Anniston"
    Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(Candidate.class);


    crit.createAlias("candidateInfo", "ci");

    crit.add(Restrictions.in("ci.city", city));
            List rsList = crit.list();
```

Now this above thing work fine if i have the value "United States-Alabama-Anniston"  in my database but the problem is in my database its only "Anniston"

do any one have any idea how to get the match if there's only "Anniston" in my database and i want to check it with "United States-Alabama-Anniston" which is in the ArrayList.

thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. You have to explain what the problem is in more details.

Comment: in my database i have a city name "Anniston"  which i want to show if i apply the criteria   crit.add(Restrictions.in("ci.city",city));   where city is an Array which have a value "UnitedStates-Anniston"  its not working ,not giving me any record(Thats the problem) ,  whereas if i change city name to only"Anniston" then it shows the record from database perfectly , i guess i need to use some Match or like statement but how ?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from comment, you have values in the string that may consist of country,state and the city separated by '-'. In this case and if format with '-' is guaranteed, your best and most efficient choice would be to just walk over array and copy part after '-' to separate array that you can use in `in` clause.

Comment: you are right , but i was doing this thing in simple sql as   match(ci.city) against('" + city + "').   i was not walking over my array for this, i just thought there could be some similar way in hibernate